# SKSpriteNode positioning math escapes me?

Tags: uibezierpath

**SKSpriteNode positioning math escapes me ?**

More specifically, the positioning required for creating a `UIBezierPath` from a `CGRect`.

A very few short code snippets follow ...

```
roomWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
roomHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

// trackOffset = a constant
tracksWidth  = roomWidth - 2*trackOffset   // inset from screen edge
tracksHeight = 0.40*roomHeight - trackOffset

// the `SKSpriteNode` = myTracks
myTracks.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

tracksPosX = 0.0
tracksPosY = -roomHeight/2 + trackOffset + tracksHeight/2
myTracks.position = CGPoint(x: tracksPosX, y: tracksPosY)
```

Later, I create a `UIBezierPath` from my `trackRect` defined as follows:

```
trackRect = CGRect(x: tracksPosX - tracksWidth/2,
                   y: tracksPosY,
                   width: tracksWidth,
                   height: tracksHeight)
trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)
```

**But** something is wrong with `y: tracksPosY` **because** with iOS, the origin is in the upper-left corner and the rectangle extends towards the lower-right corner.

**Given this spec from Apple, shouldn't it read:**

`y: tracksPosY + tracksHeight/2`**?**

Answer (score 0):

We need to try and simplify things -- and take them step-by-step.

So, let's use a simple game scene, where we'll define a `rect` and add a `SKShapeNode` with a rectangle path, and a `SKShapeNode` with an oval path:

```
import UIKit
import GameplayKit

class SimpleGameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        guard let thisSKView = self.view else { return }
        
        let sz = thisSKView.frame.size
        
        let offset: CGFloat = 80.0
        
        let x: CGFloat = offset
        let y: CGFloat = offset
        let w: CGFloat = sz.width - (offset * 2.0)
        let h: CGFloat = sz.height * 0.4
        
        let myRect: CGRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        
        let shapeNodeRect = SKShapeNode(path: UIBezierPath(rect: myRect).cgPath)
        shapeNodeRect.lineWidth = 7
        shapeNodeRect.strokeColor = .darkGray
        addChild(shapeNodeRect)
        
        let shapeNodeOval = SKShapeNode(path: UIBezierPath(ovalIn: myRect).cgPath)
        shapeNodeOval.lineWidth = 5
        shapeNodeOval.strokeColor = .systemBlue
        addChild(shapeNodeOval)
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

and, as we know, y-axis is "inverted" with scene kit, so we have an origin of `80,80` and positive values for width and height:

[image]

If we use the same values to define the rect in a "normal" app, using `CAShapeLayer`s instead of scene kit nodes:

```
import UIKit

class ShapeTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.148, green: 0.148, blue: 0.148, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let thisSKView = UIView()
        thisSKView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(thisSKView)
        
        let sz = thisSKView.frame.size
        
        let offset: CGFloat = 80.0
        
        let x: CGFloat = offset
        let y: CGFloat = offset
        let w: CGFloat = sz.width - (offset * 2.0)
        let h: CGFloat = sz.height * 0.4
        
        let myRect: CGRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        
        let shapeNodeRect = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeNodeRect.path = UIBezierPath(rect: myRect).cgPath
        shapeNodeRect.lineWidth = 7
        shapeNodeRect.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        shapeNodeRect.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeRect)
        
        let shapeNodeOval = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeNodeOval.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: myRect).cgPath
        shapeNodeOval.lineWidth = 5
        shapeNodeOval.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        shapeNodeOval.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeOval)
    }
    
}
```

we get this:

[image]

with non-inverted y-axis:

[image]

What may be confusing the issue is the fact that an inverted rectangle or oval doesn't look any different.

So, let's add an "arrow" bezier path shape:

```
    let p1: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX - 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
    let p2: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.minY)
    let p3: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX + 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
    let p4: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.maxY)
    let p5: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.minX, y: myRect.maxY)
    let p6: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.maxX, y: myRect.maxY)

    let pth = UIBezierPath()
    
    pth.move(to: p1)
    pth.addLine(to: p2)
    pth.addLine(to: p3)
    pth.move(to: p2)
    pth.addLine(to: p4)
    pth.move(to: p5)
    pth.addLine(to: p6)
```

[image]

Let's add that as another `CAShapeLayer` in our "normal" app:

```
    let shapeNodeArrow = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeNodeArrow.path = pth.cgPath
    shapeNodeArrow.lineWidth = 3
    shapeNodeArrow.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
    shapeNodeArrow.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeArrow)
```

and we get this (as expected):

[image]

If we then add that arrow bezier path as another `SKShapeNode` in our scene kit app:

```
    let shapeNodeArrow = SKShapeNode(path: pth.cgPath)
    shapeNodeArrow.lineWidth = 3
    shapeNodeArrow.strokeColor = .systemRed
    addChild(shapeNodeArrow)
```

we get this result:

[image]

and now it's pretty easy to see that the inverted y-axis ***also*** inverts the path(s) we've created.

---

Again, simplify what you're doing to make it easier to learn and understand what's going on. It also helps to add `print(...)` statements, or Debug Breakpoints, to evaluate your calculations.

Using the code you posted, if I set `trackOffset = 80.0` and then `print(trackRect)` at the end, I get (on an iPhone 15 Pro):

```
(-116.5, -215.6, 233.0, 260.8)
```

which is almost *certainly* not the rectangle origin you are going for.

---

Full code for each example...

**"normal" app with `CAShapeLayer`:**

```
class ShapeTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.148, green: 0.148, blue: 0.148, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let thisSKView = UIView()
        thisSKView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(thisSKView)
        
        let sz = thisSKView.frame.size
        
        let offset: CGFloat = 80.0
        
        let x: CGFloat = offset
        let y: CGFloat = offset
        let w: CGFloat = sz.width - (offset * 2.0)
        let h: CGFloat = sz.height * 0.4
        
        let myRect: CGRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        
        let shapeNodeRect = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeNodeRect.path = UIBezierPath(rect: myRect).cgPath
        shapeNodeRect.lineWidth = 7
        shapeNodeRect.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        shapeNodeRect.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeRect)
        
        let shapeNodeOval = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeNodeOval.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: myRect).cgPath
        shapeNodeOval.lineWidth = 5
        shapeNodeOval.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        shapeNodeOval.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeOval)
        
        let p1: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX - 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
        let p2: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.minY)
        let p3: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX + 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
        let p4: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.maxY)
        let p5: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.minX, y: myRect.maxY)
        let p6: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.maxX, y: myRect.maxY)

        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        pth.move(to: p1)
        pth.addLine(to: p2)
        pth.addLine(to: p3)
        pth.move(to: p2)
        pth.addLine(to: p4)
        pth.move(to: p5)
        pth.addLine(to: p6)

        let shapeNodeArrow = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeNodeArrow.path = pth.cgPath
        shapeNodeArrow.lineWidth = 3
        shapeNodeArrow.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
        shapeNodeArrow.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thisSKView.layer.addSublayer(shapeNodeArrow)
    }
    
}
```

---

Full code for each example...

**scene kit app with `SKShapeNode`:**

```
class SimpleGameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        guard let thisSKView = self.view else { return }
        
        let sz = thisSKView.frame.size
        
        let offset: CGFloat = 80.0
        
        let x: CGFloat = offset
        let y: CGFloat = offset
        let w: CGFloat = sz.width - (offset * 2.0)
        let h: CGFloat = sz.height * 0.4
        
        let myRect: CGRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        
        let shapeNodeRect = SKShapeNode(path: UIBezierPath(rect: myRect).cgPath)
        shapeNodeRect.lineWidth = 7
        shapeNodeRect.strokeColor = .darkGray
        addChild(shapeNodeRect)
        
        let shapeNodeOval = SKShapeNode(path: UIBezierPath(ovalIn: myRect).cgPath)
        shapeNodeOval.lineWidth = 5
        shapeNodeOval.strokeColor = .systemBlue
        addChild(shapeNodeOval)
        
        let p1: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX - 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
        let p2: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.minY)
        let p3: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX + 60.0, y: myRect.minY + 80.0)
        let p4: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.midX, y: myRect.maxY)
        let p5: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.minX, y: myRect.maxY)
        let p6: CGPoint = .init(x: myRect.maxX, y: myRect.maxY)
        
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        pth.move(to: p1)
        pth.addLine(to: p2)
        pth.addLine(to: p3)
        pth.move(to: p2)
        pth.addLine(to: p4)
        pth.move(to: p5)
        pth.addLine(to: p6)
        
        let shapeNodeArrow = SKShapeNode(path: pth.cgPath)
        shapeNodeArrow.lineWidth = 3
        shapeNodeArrow.strokeColor = .systemRed
        addChild(shapeNodeArrow)
    }
    
}
```